# File permissions on uploaded files

Tags: permissions, ftp, vsftpd

This is hopefully a simple question.  I have a VPS set up running LAMP and accepting FTP connections.  the only problem with my setup at the moment seems to be that apache is denied access to uploaded files, because the only permissions set are 'rw' for the owner.

In other words, this is what I see when I run `ls -al`

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 root         admins 4096 Jan  5 01:31 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 root         admins 4096 Jan  5 01:28 ..
-rw------- 1 gradinafrica admins   62 Jan  5 01:31 index.html
```

The third file has been uploaded by user 'gradinafrica'.  I need to make sure that it gives read/write access to the group 'admins', too.  In other words, `ls -al` should display this:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 root         admins 4096 Jan  5 01:31 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 root         admins 4096 Jan  5 01:28 ..
-rw-rw---- 1 gradinafrica admins   63 Jan  5 01:36 index.html
```

Did I set up something incorrectly in vsftpd?  How can I accomplish what I'm trying to?

Answer (score 2):

Adding `local_umask=022` to vsftpd.conf seems to have fixed the problem.